# how to pass lambda, function object or std::function as template arguments and control their arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I would like to implement some protocol as a class template with raw_write and raw_read functions as template arguments. Both raw functions has strictly defined interfaces:

```
int raw_write(uint8_t *src, size_t len);
int raw_read(uint8_t *dst, size_t maxlen);
```

Is it any way to control this interface with compilation error when somebody tries
to pass for example:

```
int raw_write2(uint16_t *src, size_t len);
```

Should I pass template arguments as objects of specified type or as a type name instantiated inside template realization?

Comment: if you're only accepting one argument type, what's the use of templating it ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I was a bit confused myself, but I *think* he wants a class template that will hold some object callable with the specified signature. But it could be a function pointer, a functor, a lambda, ... as long as it has the right signature. So [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is probably the answer in some form.

Comment: @BoBTFish : looks like you're right - reading the title too, and not just the body helps :-)

Comment: Could you give an example of how you want this to be used or NOT to be used? This is confusing me a bit, even after other users' explanations

Comment: SanderDeDycker: You're right. I would like to be able to pass any callable with strictly controlled signature.

Comment: What kind of failure do you want if someone passes in the wrong type?  Will any compilation failure do?  What is the lifetime of the resulting objects?  Do you require an implementation in a separate `cpp` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with SFINAE and some traits classes.

I suspect the best way to do it is to expect a functor that is call-compatible -- this also happens to be easier.

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T, bool=true>
struct raw_write_compatible: std::false_type {};
template<typename T, bool=true>
struct raw_read_compatible: std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct raw_write_compatible<
  T,
  std::is_convertable<
    decltype(
      std::declval<T&>()(
        std::declval<uint8_t *>(),
        std::declval<size_t>()
      )
    ),
    int
  >::value
>: std::true_type {};
template<typename T>
struct raw_read_compatible<
  T,
  std::is_convertable<
    decltype(
      std::declval<T&>()(
        std::declval<uint8_t *>(),
        std::declval<size_t>()
      )
    ),
    int
  >::value
>: std::true_type {};
```

The point of these is that `raw_read_compatible< T >::value` is `true` iff an instance of `T` can be evaluated by with the signature `(uint8_t*, size_t)`, and the return type can be converted to an `int`.

( As an aside, your "write" function signature probably should take a pointer to `const uint8_t`, because it doesn't modify that parameter. )

You'd use this like this:

```
template<typename Reader, typename Writer>
typename std::enable_if<
  raw_read_compatible<Reader>::value && raw_write_compatible<Writer>::value,
  bool // return value of do_some_io_stuff
>::type do_some_io_stuff( Reader const& reader, Writer const& writer ) {
  return true;
}
```

and `do_some_io_stuff` will match iff reader/writer can be called in the way you want.

This has the advantage that `do_some_io_stuff` fails to *match* when you try to pass in an incompatible lambda or function pointer or functor, instead of matching and then failing to compile.  In theory, that lets you override things.

The above solution requires a compiler with decent C++11 support: MSVC2012 doesn't work with the above, for example (it lacks "expression SFINAE" in its words).

A simpler solution would be to just take a `std::function< int(uint8_t*, size_t) >`, but that has two costs: first, it has a run time cost at each invocation (roughly equivalent to a `virtual` method call -- so not that high when compared to io) -- the real cost being blocking optimization over the function-call boundary.  Second you can get some failure to compile instead of failure to match the signature errors in my experience (I'm not sure if the C++11 standard has specified that `std::function`'s "lambda" constructor should only match when passed a compatible type, but I think I've seen implementations that fail that test).

The advantage of the `std::function` solution is that it is much simpler, it allows putting the implementation in a separate file, and the intent is easier to understand.

Comment: I'm really impressed with this solution!

Comment: @ardabro thanks.  It would be better if I wrote or found a "is signature compatible" traits class: something like `is_signature_compatible< int(uint8_t*,size_t), T >::value`.

Answer (score 7):

I *think* this is the desired (or at least *a*) solution using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) to store the callable (not requiring a used defined `template` class):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct protocol_callbacks
{
    using func_t = std::function<int(uint8_t*, size_t)>;

    protocol_callbacks(func_t a_reader, func_t a_writer) :
        reader(a_reader),
        writer(a_writer) {}
    func_t reader;
    func_t writer;
};

int writer(uint8_t*, size_t) { return 0; }
int reader(uint8_t*, size_t) { return 0; }

int bad_writer(uint16_t*, size_t) { return 0; }

int main ()
{
    protocol_callbacks pc1(reader, writer);
    protocol_callbacks pc2([](uint8_t*, size_t) { return 0; },
                           [](uint8_t*, size_t) { return 0; });
    //protocol_callbacks pc3(bad_writer, reader);
}
```

Use of `bad_writer` causes a compilation failure (without `bad_writer` http://ideone.com/hG7tqc and with `bad_writer` http://ideone.com/roMJgM).

Comment: Good and simple. No templates necessary. Thanks.